# Click a href button with no class, id or link text with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I'm crawling the webpage: www.ogimet.com and I want to click a href button.

This is the html code:

```
<a href="/sondc.phtml"><b>S</b>ondeos por territorios</a>
```

How can i click this button? If it's possible avoiding `driver.find_element_by_xpath()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you provided does have a link text that can be used to select it, you just need to remove the bold tags, so `Sondeos por territorios` instead of `<b>S</b>ondeos por territorios`.

Using [`driver.find_element_by_link_text`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html):

```py
link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Sondeos por territorios')
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it, I created a re-usable function that returns the first element by tag and matching attributes.

```
def getElementByTagAndAttributes(driver, tag, **kwargs):
    for element in driver.find_elements_by_tag_name(tag):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            attribute = element.get_attribute(key)
            if attribute != value:
                break
        else:
            return element

getElementByTagAndAttributes(driver, "a", href="/sondc.phtml").click()
```